# How to make a google generated chart as part of jquery dialogue box?

Tags: jquery

My actual requirement is that I need to open a pop up on click of a Stock Name , so i thought to make chart as part of jquery dialogue

The issue i am facing is that Chart is not being a part of jquery dialogue

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    $("#dialog").show();
});
var mydata = [
    ['13-Oct', 1097.95, 1113.45, 1109.95, 1132],
    ['14-Oct', 1095.6, 1101.15, 1113.45, 1117],
    ['15-Oct', 1092.1, 1129.2, 1116, 1132],
    ['16-Oct', 1130, 1170.3, 1130, 1182.4],
    ['19-Oct', 1144.5, 1162.15, 1174, 1182.2]
];
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata, true);
    var days = 5;
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        chartArea: {
            left: '7%',
            width: '70%'
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                type: 'candlesticks'
            },
            1: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").hide();
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto"
}); 
$("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Test Charts");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use create dialog box with `autoOpen : false`, then bind the `#open` link with function containing

```
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/25/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working great , i also wanted jquery dialog to close when clicked outside it , i made a new code with your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/26/ and could you please tell me why the jquery dialog is not getting closed when clicked outside ??